writing to the VAR_INPUT inside the function block has the same behavior as VAR_IN_OUT
I attach this image where you can see that the input variable is written inside the function block and the compiler does not raise any warnings, but the value of the variable is also propagated to the caller. This seems like very strange behavior to me

I tested this example with twincat3 4024.22 and 4024.47, but the behavior is identical, I would expect the compiler to issue a warning or an error and for the value not to propagate to the caller.

It is one thing to change internal variable and another thing to change external. What I mean is this. You change in0 inside FB but you do not bind it to a variable when call it. Test this. Create variable in Program and set it to in0. Then see if t1.in0 is changed and variable in a program.

yes that's exactly what I did
//in myFB
var_input myVarInput: bool;
myVarInput:=true;
// in program
instanceMyFB();
programVar:=instanceMyFb.myVarInput;
// now value of programVar is TRUE !

You did not get it. For instance MyBool := FALSE; MyFB(in0 := MyBool); MyNewBool := MyBool; I understand that MyFB.In0 might be TRUE but say what is MyNewBool? Or try to call it like this  MyFB(in0 := FALSE);

As far as I am concerned, thank god TwinCAT does not take that weird, ladder-inspired IN/OUT approach too rigidly. The concept of "inputs" and "outputs" quickly breaks down once you stop thinking about just I/O devices and circuit diagrams.
VAR, VAR_INPUT, VAR_OUTPUT, they are all just member variables (in the OO sense) with constraints that are easy to bypass anyway as soon as you involve a pointer or reference. If you think of them this way, then what you see is not weird.
You could say a "VAR_INPUT" is basically a VAR that you can read and write from outside its function block. Think of it as "WRITABLE_PUBLIC_VAR". This is how I use them.
According to the IEC 61131-3 standard, an input variable must not be changed within a POU precisely to avoid this kind of confusion. I personally do not follow this guideline, because I work exclusively with structured text, and I do not use VAR_INPUT to connect function blocks together (I do it through reference injection and other methods). If you were to create a diagram out of my blocks, there would not be a single connection between them.
CODESYS note about IEC 61131 recommendation
If you are writing a library for general reuse, probably your intended audience expects "well-behaved" function blocks that mostly follow this rule. If not, then it is a design consideration influenced by your specific challenge, preferences, experience, etc.

thank you for your point of view, it's food for thought. What strikes me is that there is no separation between function block and calling code.
It seems strange that the compiler does not report within the FB that I am writing to a VAR_INPUT. Furthermore, if the calling code uses the VAR_INPUT of an instance of that block to read, it could vary its value just like a VAR_OUTPUT

Just to add, since there seemed to be a confusion with VAR_IN_OUT, differently from VAR_INPUT which copies the value, VAR_IN_OUT passes the value by reference, which means that if you pass a value to the function block and modify the value inside that block, the value outside also changes even if you don't explicitly read the in_out variable: x_before := x; fb(x_in_out := x); x_after := x; // x_before may not equal x_after

"I personally do not follow this guideline, because I work exclusively with structured text" , I too work in ST, but that doesn't mean this guideline should be ignored. Often when using TON blocks with compicated expressions in the IN input which I want to reuse, instead of repeating those expressions or writing them to a temporary variable, I just reuse that input, for example myton(IN := (a AND b) or (c AND d) or e, PT := time); IF myton.IN THEN text := 'timer is running!'; END_IF. This wouldn't be possible if TON didn't "behave well". Just something to watch out for.

When the result of an operation is used repeatedly, reusing it to avoid repeated code and improving efficiency is basically caching. If you use the input of a function block as your cache and others rely on it, and at some point you remove the block to which this input belongs, then you break all your references. For sure, in a case like that, I would define a variable to store the value, and feed that value to other blocks from that variable, not from an input.

Of course, that's normally the case. What surprised me is that the compiler doesn't try to dissuade you from this practice. In other environments, not setting an input parameter or writing an input variable within its FB creates a compilation error or a warning.

@user24620163, what you say is probably true if "other environments" means "other automation-centric" environments", but it no longer is you extend the definition to include general development environments. In the general context the concept of blocks with inputs and outputs as the basis for programming is an oddity, and it is not the only way to design physical systems that deal with physical inputs and outputs. For what I do, it would be a poor approach.
